# Problems setting up Libgdx Bullet wrapper for Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, bullet, bulletphysics

I am new to Libgdx and Bullet Physics, and have been unable to get Bullet to work on my Android device.

I have gotten the same program to work on the Desktop version, and have copied the `libgdx-bullet.so` files to armeabi and `armeabi-v7a`, but the Android version crashes with the error 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.Bullet`

Comment: That was an interesting story.

Comment: @Mureinik What code would you like to see? The code itself works just fine and I can run it on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out why I could not get the program to work on Android when it worked on the Desktop version. I needed to add the `gdx-bullet.jar` file to the list of things to be exported, it is not enough to just add it to the list of libraries.